# Could accessing a variable directly (rather than with a pointer and dereferecer) give different values?

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I know it's an odd question and I risk showing my greenness, but I'm tearing my hair out here.

I have a C++ example that works as expected. Here's a snippet of the bothersome bit:

```
BIRDFRAME frame;
birdGetMostRecentFrame(GROUP_ID,&frame);
BIRDREADING *bird_data;
bird_time=frame.dwTime;
for(FBBloop=FBBstart; FBBloop<FBBend; FBBloop++ )
{                   
    bird_data = &frame.reading[FBBloop];
    // Do stuff
}
```

Note that `bird_data` is a pointer and is assigned the address of `frame.reading[FBBloop]`. My app is written in C# and so doesn't have any of this pointer malarkey. The corresponding bit looks like this:

```
FlockOfBirds.BIRDFRAME frame = new FlockOfBirds.BIRDFRAME();
FlockOfBirds.birdGetMostRecentFrame(1, ref frame);
Console.WriteLine("T:{0}",frame.dwTime.ToString());
FlockOfBirds.BIRDREADING reading;
for (int k = 1; k <= sysconf.byNumDevices; k++)
{
    reading = frame.readings[k];
    Console.WriteLine("  [{0}][{1}][{2}]", reading.position.nX.ToString(), reading.position.nY.ToString(), reading.position.nZ.ToString());
}
```

The problem is that in the C# example, only `reading[1]` has meaningful data. In the C++ example both `bird_data[1]` and `bird_data[2]` have good data. Oddly, `reading[2-n]` don't all have zeroed values, but appear to be random and constant. Here's what the output from the C# app looks like:

```
T:17291325
  [30708][-2584][-5220]
  [-19660][1048][-31310]

T:17291334
  [30464][-2588][-5600]
  [-19660][1048][-31310]

T:17291346
  [30228][-2600][-5952]
  [-19660][1048][-31310]

T:17291354
  [30120][-2520][-6264]
  [-19660][1048][-31310]

T:17291363
  [30072][-2388][-6600]
  [-19660][1048][-31310]
```

Notice that the top triplet of each entry is slightly different from those of the entries pre- and succeeding it. In the C++ app, the bottom line behaves similarly, but here it stays the same throughout.

Could this be to do with the lack of pointing and dereferencing? Or am I barking up entirely the wrong tree? Have I done something else that's obviously stupid? Most importantly: how do I make it work?

---

**Update: Structs & externs**

C++

```
// Bird reading structure
typedef struct tagBIRDREADING
{
    BIRDPOSITION    position;   // position of receiver
    BIRDANGLES      angles;     // orientation of receiver, as angles
    BIRDMATRIX      matrix;     // orientation of receiver, as matrix
    BIRDQUATERNION  quaternion; // orientation of receiver, as quaternion
    WORD            wButtons;   // button states
}
BIRDREADING;

// Bird frame structure
//
// NOTE: In stand-alone mode, the bird reading is stored in reading[0], and
//  all other array elements are unused.  In master/slave mode, the "reading"
//  array is indexed by bird number - for example, bird #1 is at reading[1],
//  bird #2 is at reading[2], etc., and reading[0] is unused.
typedef struct tagBIRDFRAME
{
    DWORD           dwTime;     // time at which readings were taken, in msecs
    BIRDREADING     reading[BIRD_MAX_DEVICE_NUM + 1];  // reading from each bird
}
BIRDFRAME;

BOOL DLLEXPORT birdGetMostRecentFrame(int nGroupID, BIRDFRAME *pframe);
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public struct BIRDREADING
{
        public BIRDPOSITION position;
        public BIRDANGLES angles;
        public BIRDMATRIX matrix;
        public BIRDQUATERNION quaternion;
        public ushort wButtons;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public struct BIRDFRAME
{
        public uint dwTime;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 127)]
        public BIRDREADING[] readings;
}

[DllImport(@"Bird.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool birdGetMostRecentFrame(int nGroupID, ref BIRDFRAME frame);
```

---

** Update 2: More structs: **

C++

```
#pragma pack(1) // pack the following structures on one-byte boundaries

// Bird position structure
typedef struct tagBIRDPOSITION
{
    short   nX;         // x-coordinate
    short   nY;         // y-coordinate
    short   nZ;         // z-coordinate
}
BIRDPOSITION;

// Bird angles structure
typedef struct tagBIRDANGLES
{
    short   nAzimuth;   // azimuth angle
    short   nElevation; // elevation angle
    short   nRoll;      // roll angle
}
BIRDANGLES;

// Bird matrix structure
typedef struct tagBIRDMATRIX
{
    short   n[3][3];    // array of matrix elements
}
BIRDMATRIX;

// Bird quaternion structure
typedef struct tagBIRDQUATERNION
{
    short   nQ0;        // q0
    short   nQ1;        // q1
    short   nQ2;        // q2
    short   nQ3;        // q3
}
BIRDQUATERNION;

#pragma pack()  // resume normal packing of structures
```

C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BIRDPOSITION
{
    public short nX;
    public short nY;
    public short nZ;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BIRDANGLES
{
    public short nAzimuth;  // azimuth angle
    public short nElevation;    // elevation angle
    public short nRoll;     // roll angle
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct BIRDMATRIX
{
    public fixed short n[9];
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BIRDQUATERNION
{
    public short nQ0;       // q0
    public short nQ1;       // q1
    public short nQ2;       // q2
    public short nQ3;       // q3
}
```

Comment: I can't say I understand what all your objects might be doing, or why this wouldn't cause a failure but most arrays are zero based, is this definitely supposed to be starting with `int k = 1;`?

Comment: Yeah, it's weird, but definitely starting from 1. 0 is reserved for a special case where there's only one value to query.

Comment: "0 is reserved for a special case where there's only one value" - So if you have 2 items, the array will have 3 elements in it with the first one at index 0 being unused? If so, it seems like there should be some thought given to that.  Especially since index 0 already handles the 'special case' of a one item array quite nicely.

Comment: Hey, I didn't write the library! ;) If you want the guts, the array is always fixed at 127. If only one instrument is connected and is in "standalone" mode, indices 1-126 are ignored. If, as in my case, 2 are connected, 0 and 3-126 are ignored.

Comment: We're reduced to guessing without the definitions of the structs and some knowledge of what's behind `birdGetMostRecentFrame`. Is there some P/Invoke mixed in somewhere too?

Comment: @David - I've updated the question to include the relevant structs and externs. Really appreciate all the help on this - let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: need declarations of BIRDPOSITION    BIRDANGLES    BIRDMATRIX    BIRDQUATERNION, and the sizeof(BIRDFRAME) in C# and C++

Comment: OK, updated the question to include BIRDPOSITION BIRDANGLES BIRDMATRIX & BIRDQUATERNION. Not sure what you mean by the last part.

Comment: Marshal.SizeOf(new BIRDFRAME()); in C# is 5084 ... can you please check if you get the same sizeof() in C++ ?

Comment: I checked  int sz = sizeof(tagBIRDFRAME); gives the same, so sizes are equal for marshalling... hmmm

Comment: Thanks Marino - I'm not very confident with C++.

Comment: please check my post and try the projects, see if you get ok values...

Comment: Will do. Just installing VS2010 on my home laptop. (https://twitter.com/tdwright/status/61062151300841472)

Comment: Also, this question made me realise that SE sites need to support collapsible regions. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26279/collapsible-region/88374#88374)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your struct in two projects (C++/C#) and it seems to work correctly.

I use this in C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

#pragma pack(1) // pack the following structures on one-byte boundaries

// Bird position structure
typedef struct tagBIRDPOSITION
{
    short   nX;         // x-coordinate
    short   nY;         // y-coordinate
    short   nZ;         // z-coordinate
}
BIRDPOSITION;

// Bird angles structure
typedef struct tagBIRDANGLES
{
    short   nAzimuth;   // azimuth angle
    short   nElevation; // elevation angle
    short   nRoll;      // roll angle
}
BIRDANGLES;

// Bird matrix structure
typedef struct tagBIRDMATRIX
{
    short   n[3][3];    // array of matrix elements
}
BIRDMATRIX;

// Bird quaternion structure
typedef struct tagBIRDQUATERNION
{
    short   nQ0;        // q0
    short   nQ1;        // q1
    short   nQ2;        // q2
    short   nQ3;        // q3
}
BIRDQUATERNION;

#pragma pack()  // resume normal packing of structures

typedef struct tagBIRDREADING
{
    BIRDPOSITION    position;   // position of receiver
    BIRDANGLES      angles;     // orientation of receiver, as angles
    BIRDMATRIX      matrix;     // orientation of receiver, as matrix
    BIRDQUATERNION  quaternion; // orientation of receiver, as quaternion
    WORD            wButtons;   // button states
}
BIRDREADING;

#define BIRD_MAX_DEVICE_NUM 126

// Bird frame structure
//
// NOTE: In stand-alone mode, the bird reading is stored in reading[0], and
//  all other array elements are unused.  In master/slave mode, the "reading"
//  array is indexed by bird number - for example, bird #1 is at reading[1],
//  bird #2 is at reading[2], etc., and reading[0] is unused.
typedef struct tagBIRDFRAME
{
    DWORD           dwTime;     // time at which readings were taken, in msecs
    BIRDREADING     reading[BIRD_MAX_DEVICE_NUM + 1];  // reading from each bird
}
BIRDFRAME;

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) BOOL birdGetMostRecentFrame(int nGroupID, BIRDFRAME *pframe) {

    pframe->dwTime = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pframe->reading)/sizeof(*pframe->reading); i++) {
        pframe->reading[i] = BIRDREADING();
        pframe->reading[i].position.nX = (short)i;
        pframe->reading[i].position.nY = (short)i + 1;
        pframe->reading[i].position.nZ = (short)i + 2;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

And this in C#:

```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BIRDPOSITION
{
    public short nX;
    public short nY;
    public short nZ;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BIRDANGLES
{
    public short nAzimuth;  // azimuth angle
    public short nElevation;    // elevation angle
    public short nRoll;     // roll angle
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct BIRDMATRIX
{
    public fixed short n[9];
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct BIRDQUATERNION
{
    public short nQ0;       // q0
    public short nQ1;       // q1
    public short nQ2;       // q2
    public short nQ3;       // q3
}

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public struct BIRDREADING
{
        public BIRDPOSITION position;
        public BIRDANGLES angles;
        public BIRDMATRIX matrix;
        public BIRDQUATERNION quaternion;
        public ushort wButtons;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public struct BIRDFRAME
{
        public uint dwTime;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 127)]
        public BIRDREADING[] readings;
}

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport(@"Bird.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool birdGetMostRecentFrame(int nGroupID, ref BIRDFRAME frame);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BIRDFRAME bf = new BIRDFRAME();

            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {                
                bf.readings = new BIRDREADING[127];
            }

            if (birdGetMostRecentFrame(0, ref bf)) {
                listBox1.Items.Add(bf.dwTime.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(bf.dwTime.ToString());
                for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
                {
                    var reading = bf.readings[k];
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  [{0}][{1}][{2}]", reading.position.nX.ToString(), reading.position.nY.ToString(), reading.position.nZ.ToString()));
                    listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("  [{0}][{1}][{2}]", reading.position.nX.ToString(), reading.position.nY.ToString(), reading.position.nZ.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In both cases (reading initialized as new in C#, or not it gives back meaningful data:

```
40067905
  [1][2][3]
  [2][3][4]
  [3][4][5]
40068653
  [1][2][3]
  [2][3][4]
  [3][4][5]
40069418
  [1][2][3]
  [2][3][4]
  [3][4][5]
40072585
  [1][2][3]
  [2][3][4]
  [3][4][5]
```

Did it on Windows7 64 bit.
I'm attaching a ZIP with both projects for VS2010.

Here is the link:

http://hotfile.com/dl/115296617/9644496/testCS.zip.html

It seems that you are setting wrong values inside that position struct :/

Comment: OK, so it seems pretty clear that everything is being marshalled correctly. I guess the problem must lie somewhere else in the C# app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `sysconf.byNumDevices == 1` so `i <= sysconf.byNumDevices` loops only once and you are reading uninitialized memory segments.

Try printing out `sysconf.byNumDevices`, and if it is 1 try to trace that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in .NET are zero based, not one based. Could that be it? Of course, .NET also has strict bounds checking so I would have expected your "last" access to the array to fail with an exception too.

Without having access to `FlockOfBirds` source, I am not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: I should have pointed out that the 0th element is skipped as it's reserved for a special case. I believe C++ arrays are 0 indexed too.

Comment: Yes, c++ arrays are also 0 based.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: do you actually need the ref when passing to your method?

```
FlockOfBirds.BIRDFRAME frame = new FlockOfBirds.BIRDFRAME();
FlockOfBirds.birdGetMostRecentFrame(1, ref frame);
```

If I'm not mistaken then in c# all classes are passed by reference anyway. I might be mad but aren't you passing a ref to a ref?

Comment: I *do* remember something about all non-simple types being passed by ref, but there's a big difference between passing by ref and passing a ref.

Comment: Had another think about it and what I've found is: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=474375
So how about trying to marshal DWORD/WORD into int/short not uint/ushort ?